# jQuery .submit() Not handling my form, instead the form action is taken

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit my form via jQuery and AJAX, but it seems that the action of self (index.php) ends up being taken, not the jQuery submit handler.  Any ideas why?

```
    <form id="artist_signup" action="index.php" method="get" oninput="AoutName.value=ANAME.value">
    <input type="hidden" name="ajax" value="true" />
    <div class="inlineInput">
        <input type="text" name="ANAME" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <div class="inlineInput">
        <input type="text" name="LOCATION" placeholder="City, State">
    </div>

    <div class="inlineInput">
        <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <div class="inlineInput">
        <input type="url" name="AWEBSITE" placeholder="www.myawesomeband.com">
    </div>

    <div class="submitContainer">
        <input type="submit" value="Sen" class="donateButton formSubmit">
    </div>
    <div id="artist_message"></div>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#artist_signup').submit(function() {
        $("#artist_message").html("<span class='error'>Adding your email address...</span>");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/store-address.php',
            data: $('#artist_signup').serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#artist_message').html(msg);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action, which is form submit. 
This can be done by using `e.preventDefault()` You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#artist_signup').submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#artist_message").html("<span class='error'>Adding your email address...</span>");
       $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/store-address.php',
            data: $('#artist_signup').serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#artist_message').html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't seem to do the trick, still getting the default form action submission.

Comment: did you reload? might be a caching issue

Comment: Sorry, that does work.  Very stupid mistake on my part.  I had jQuery being loaded lower in my document than this jquery code. :( so silly.

Comment: Oh.. then it should have thrown an error `$` is undefined. Console logs are good places to see if any errors are thrown. Glad it got fixed

Answer (score 0):

When using the submit function, it's natural action is to postback to whatever the form action is.  What you can do is add a parameter to your function of `e`.  This would represent the event object which has properties and methods that relate to the event itself.  With this you can do `e.preventDefault();` which will stop the form action from occurring.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#artist_signup').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#artist_message").html("<span class='error'>Adding your email address...   </span>");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/store-address.php',
        data: $('#artist_signup').serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#artist_message').html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```